# Java drawing tiles with random color size?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Well I've read some code and came across this:

```
private int[] tiles = new int [64 * 64];
```

Thats the tiles array.

And that sets a random colors to the tiles array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 64 * 64; i++) {
        this.tiles[i] = rand.nextInt(0xffffff);
    }
```

And now rendering

```
public void render() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
            int index = (j / 50) * 64;
            pixels[j + i * this.width] = tiles[index];
        }
    }
}
```

(Rendering outside of that class, but it doesnt matter).

Output:

[image]
but if I change j / 50 to j / 16, the tiles gets smaller and becomes this:

[image]
Why does this happen? after all the variable index only gets the color from the array? why does it make it big? j changes everytime, shouldnt the colors be different everytime?

Can someone explain this please? I am kinda confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is calculating an `index` into the list of colours, you have only created 64 different random colours.

The loop works out the `index` of which of those 64 colours to use by converting the x co-ordinate into the `index` using `(j / 50) * 64`.

Because j is an integer `j/50` will give you steps, 0-49 becomes 0, 50-99 becomes 1, etc.

When you then multiply by 64 you are still keeping those steps.

If you change the divide from being a 50 to being a 16 then you are making the steps 16 pixels wide rather than 50 pixels wide.

Just be careful that you don't run off the edge of your random colours array!